# How to programmatically visually select a text block?

Tags: vimscript, visual-mode

Is there a way to select a text block (e.g. a first word "TODO:") programmatically (with some commands or functions from a script)? Not simply highlight, like with a search, but visually select like with mouse?

Comment: Are you asking how to enter visual mode and select a search pattern?

Comment: Yes. Only not manually, but from a script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are looking to visually select a search pattern you can do it using two commands. For example searching for "TODO...." lines:

```
/^TODO.*$/s
v//e
```

This will search your your pattern and then visually select to the end of it.

If you want to move this to a function and then be able to call it in a single action:

```
function! VisualSelectSearch (query)
  execute "normal /".a:query."/s\<CR>v//e\<CR>"
endfunction

command! -nargs=+ VSS call VisualSelectSearch(<q-args>)
```

Now you can type `:VSS ^TODO.*$` and visually select the next instance. If you want to call the function directly in a script use `VisualSelectSearch("^TODO.*$")`.

Comment: I needed to select text in autocommand, and this code works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Any sequence of key presses can be represented in vimscript with the `:normal` command. For instance, to visually select the next occurrence of `"TODO:"` you might normally hit the following keys:

```
/TODO:<CR>        jump to the next occurence of TODO:
v                 start a visual selection (on the T)
f:                jump to the next ':'
```

To simulate these key presses in vimscript, you'd want to write something like:

```
normal! /TODO:<CR>vf:
```

However, typing `<CR>` will literally type `< C R >` instead of enter. To get around this, we have to wrap this in an execute command:

```
execute "normal! /TODO:\<CR>vf:"
```

I recommend reading `:help normal` and [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/29.html) for more information.

Comment: Unfortunately this code doesn't work from autocommand. But the variant from the previous answer does. Can't tell for sure why.

Comment: Whoops, forgot to escape `<CR>`. My solution is now virtually the same as jecxjo 's, except the function/command and slightly different interpretation of the problem. I'll leave it here as we described things slightly differently.